# How can I make this function actually work in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I am trying to factor out a snippit of code I have ALL OVER my NSIS installer.  The snippet is as follows:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3'
Pop $0

${If} $0 != 0
   Pop $0
   Push ".NET 3.5 failed to install: $\n$0"
   Call DetailPrintTS
   StrCpy $Errors "$Errors Errors From .NET 3.5 install:$\n$0$\n$\n"
${EndIf}
```

So I'd like to factor this to something like:

```
Function LoggedExec
   Pop $0
   Pop $1

   nsExec::ExecToStack $0
   Pop $0

   ${If} $0 != 0
      Pop $0
      Push "$1 failed to install: $\n$0"
      Call DetailPrintTS
      StrCpy $Errors "$Errors Errors From $1 install:$\n$0$\n$\n"
   ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

and then call it as follows:

```
Push 'Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3'
Push '.NET 3.5'
Call LoggedExec
```

Note that DetailPrintTS is another function I made that includes a timestamp in DetailPrint:

```
Function DetailPrintTS
   Pop $7

   ${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6

   DetailPrint "$4:$5:$6 -- $7$\n"
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: so, what is the question? Beware that from your snippet, if you push the command then the text for the log, you need to pop in reversed order `pop $1` then `pop $0`

Comment: I think you just answered my question...

Comment: I can make it into a true answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `Push` / `Pop` are acting on a stack (in other words, a lifo: last in, first out).

From your snippet, you seem to `Pop` the arguments in `LoggedExec` in the same order that they were `Push`ed. Instead, if you `Push` the command and after the text for the log, you need to `Pop` in reversed order:

```
Push 'Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3'
Push '.NET 3.5'
Call LoggedExec

;in LoggedExec
pop $1
pop $0
```